# What is prefs:root for keyboard text replacement in ios?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know the prefs:root for keyboard text replacement in ios

I tried prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/TEXTREPLACEMENT

Comment: Fyi if you use this in an app you submit for review you will be rejected for private api use

Answer (score 0):

prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/USER_DICTIONARY